# Spaces inside brace expansion led to weird behavior

Tags: bash

A few days ago, my lab's server suffered a serious meltdown when one of our interns accidentally copy-pasted this code on `bash` trying to delete node.js.

```
$ rm -rfv /usr/{bin/node,lib / node,share / man /* / node.*};
```

They tried a [brace expansion](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion) to list up directories to delete, but notice spaces between the directory separators (`/`). This ended up deleting everything on our server because they applied `sudo`.
I tried this command on my virtual machine and confirmed that it was pretty much equivalent to `rm -rf /`.

I'm confused about the way `bash` interpreted the statement. When I try to create a simple, nondestructive command that does similar things (spaces working as separators for expansion,) I don't seem to be able to pull that off. I tried the first command but with `for` loop in bash:

```
$ for f in /usr/{bin/node,lib / node,share / man /* / node.*}; do echo $f; done
```

which listed some contents in node.js **and** the directories in `/`. This should confirm that this is not a special feature in `rm`.

But when I try something like this:

```
$ for f in {a,b c,d e}; echo $f
```

It results in a syntax error near `echo` where I expected a to e, each letter in a single line.

I did some research, but I couldn't find anything that explains this behavior.
Can someone please tell me, in the first command, how did `bash` interpret this command?

---

p.s. I found out that in `zsh` the '`for` loop test' version doesn't work. Never tried the real '`rm` test' though. I'm scared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must **`\`-escape all spaces that are part of your brace expansion**:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {a,b\ c}
a
b c
```

Brace expansions only work:

- when they're neither **neither single- nor double-quoted** (you got that part right)
- ***and* when they're recognized as a *single word*** (token) by the shell (that's where your attempt fell short) - hence the **need for *character-individual* quoting of spaces with `\`**.

Without this, `bash` breaks what you meant to be a brace expansion into *multiple* arguments, and brace expansion never happens - see below.

---

As for how `bash` parses `/usr/{bin/node,lib / node,share / man /* / node.*}`:
The following tells you the resulting arguments (with actual globbing omitted to better demonstrate what happens):

```
$1=/usr/{bin/node,lib
$2=/
$3=node,share
$4=/
$5=man
$6=/*
$7=/
$8=node.*}
```

As you can see:

- The unescaped spaces caused the word-splitting to occur by spaces, breaking what you meant to be brace expressions into multiple arguments.
- One of the resulting arguments `/*`, unfortunately, matches all (non-hidden) items in the *root* directory, and therefore wreaks havoc when passed to `sudo rm`.